# ESlint override rule by nested directory

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I want to disable rule for all files inside nested directory. I found examples only for exact path or by file extension. But it is not what I want.

We use it for shared config and don't know where this directory will be. We have many of them.

I'm trying config like this:

```
{
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/test/**/*',
      ],
      rules: {
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off"
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

But glob like `**/test/**/*` and many others didn't not work.

Can someone help to reach this goal?

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work.

How were you testing this? If it's an extension like VSCode you may need to refresh things to see latest definitions loaded.

If you are using a eslint service like [esprint](https://github.com/pinterest/esprint) you will also need to restart it to grab latest definitions.

**Caching**
Make sure that eslint is not configured to cache results to avoid having to cache bust when debugging things. [eslint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)

Here's an example for a react-native app with multiple overrides

```
module.exports = {
  ...baseConfig,
  overrides: [
    typescriptOverrides,
    e2eOverrides,
    themeOverrides,
    {
      files: ['**/*.style.js'],
      rules: {
        'sort-keys': [
          'error',
          'asc',
          {
            caseSensitive: true,
            natural: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      files: ['**/*.test.js'],
      rules: {
        'arrow-body-style': 'off',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

**Debugging the glob matcher**

1. Run eslint in debug mode and see all the files being run example `DEBUG=eslint:cli-engine npx eslint src/**/*.test.js`
2. You can test your glob patterns by running a ls command. Example: `ls ./src/**/*.test.js` will either return all the files or 'no matches found'.